# How to make website and android App togather

Tags: android, node.js, rest

is it possible to make website in node with template engine and restful api (together) for android application ..

I know it is possible when using react For website but i have no idea how to work with template engine

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking but if you want to create a website that can act like a native-app you might have a look at [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) (PWA).

On the other hand, if your idea is to "reuse" code, [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) is a good solution.